# how to get know the client port and ip address in client socket program in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, client-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get know the client port and ip address in client socket program in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876303/how-to-get-know-the-client-port-and-ip-address-in-client-socket-program-in-java)

I created a multiple client- server communication in c# using socket. i have a single      server and a client. i want to test my program with multiple clients. i m planning to create a stimulator which dynamically create ip and port.. for that i just want to know how to set the client ip and port in the socket program. can anyone help me.

```
socket m_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to set the client ip and port in the socket

Before you issue a `Socket.Connect()`, you can `Bind()` the socket to a local address like this:

```
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
var addr = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 115 });
var ep = new IPEndPoint(addr, 0);
socket.Bind(ep);
```

However, as soon as you supply an IP address that is not bound to any adapter on your machine, a "The requested address is not valid in its context." exception will be thrown.

> i want to test my program with multiple clients

So just run your client multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the MSDN [Socket Constructor (AddressFamily, SocketType, ProtocolType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b86d684.aspx) topic?
There's a pretty obvious example on the page.